# Behavior of "unquote" when used as the second to last symbol in a quasiquoted proper list

Tags: scheme, racket, quasiquotes

I am trying to produce the list `(1 unquote 2)` using quasiquote. I have tried this:

```lisp
`(1 unquote 2)
```

However, in Racket, MIT Scheme and Chez Scheme, I get a dotted list: `'(1 . 2)`.

So I tried this:

```lisp
`(1 'unquote 2)
```

However, I get `(1 'unquote 2)`.

I finally got the list I wanted using this technique:

```lisp
`(1 unquote 2 ,((lambda (x) x) 'unquote) 2)  ; Returns: '(1 unquote 2)
```

Why do I get a dotted list out of a quasiquoted proper list when `unquote` is the second to last element in the quasiquoted list?

Actually, it does not always produce a dotted list. For example:

```
`(1 unquote (list 2 3 4))  ; Returns: '(1 2 3 4)
```

Please explain this strange behavior of unquote when it is the second to last element in a quasiquoted list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(a b c)` is a shorthand for `(a . (b . (c . ())))`.

So `(quasiquote (1 unquote 2))` is really `(quasiquote (1 . (unquote 2)))` which is `'(1 . 2)`.

(Or if you want to fully expand it, `(quasiquote (1 unquote 2))` is `(quasiquote . ((1 . (unquote . (2 . ()))) . ()))`)

Similarly, `(quasiquote (1 unquote (list 2 3 4)))` is really `(quasiquote (1 . (unquote (list 2 3 4))))` = `(quasiquote (1 . (2 3 4)))` = `'(1 2 3 4)`.

By the way, an easier way to produce `'(1 unquote 2)` using quasiquote is:

```
`(1 ,'unquote 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [R5RS](https://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/),

> Unpredictable behavior can result if any of the symbols `quasiquote`,
> `unquote`, or `unquote-splicing` appear in positions within a <qq
> template> otherwise than as described above.

And your positions are not "as described above" - the form must be `(unquote expression  ...)`.

It has been upgraded to a syntax violation in R6RS.

Comment: The first is a printing artefact; look at  its `car`, `cadr`, and `caddr`. I don't have time to investigate the other question for you.

Answer (score 0):

*[writing an answer rather than a comment because it's impossible to format backticks properly in a comment. Lisp/Scheme still handles this better than markdown ;-) ]*

As others have explained (esp. Sorawee), `unquote` (aka `,`) is a special name that is treated specially when inside an `quasiquote`d list (aka the backtick). To prevent its special meaning, a simple workaround is to make sure the special name doesn't appear textually.
Note that `unquote` does not have a special meaning inside `quote` (by contrast to inside `quasiquote`).

Thus this will work in all variants of Scheme:

```lisp
(define unquote-sym 'unquote) ; `unquote` is inside `quote`, so it's a mere symbol here

`(1 ,unquote-sym 2) ; '(1 unquote 2)
```

Comment: Okay, turns out the backtick just needs to be preceded with an antislash `\`` in SO markdown

Comment: Please read my answer to [How do I escape a backtick ` within in-line code in Markdown?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/347313/405102)